# Replace the string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, python-re, parentheses

I have the following dataframe (df):

| shape | data |
| --- | --- |
| POINT | POINT (4495 33442) |
| POLYGON | POLYGON ((6324 32691, 6326 32691, 6330 32691, 6333 32693, 6332 32696, 6329 32700, 6328 32704, 6327 32707, 6325 32710, 6322 32713, 6319 32716, 6316 32719, 6313 32722, 6310 32725, 6307 32728, 6303 32728, 6299 32727, 6295 32727, 6291 32730, 6288 32733, 6285 32735, 6281 32735, 6277 32735, 6275 32732, 6274 32729, 6274 32725, 6272 32722, 6269 32720, 6265 32719, 6261 32719, 6258 32716, 6257 32712, 6259 32708, 6262 32705, 6265 32702, 6268 32701, 6272 32701, 6276 32701, 6279 32702, 6283 32702, 6287 32702, 6291 32699, 6294 32696, 6297 32693, 6300 32692, 6304 32692, 6308 32692, 6312 32692, 6316 32692, 6320 32693, 6324 32691)) |
| POINT | POINT (4673 33465) |
| POLYGON | POLYGON ((5810 33296, 5813 33297, 5816 33299, 5819 33301, 5822 33303, 5826 33306, 5829 33307, 5833 33307, 5836 33308, 5837 33312, 5837 33316, 5836 33319, 5834 33323, 5832 33327, 5830 33330, 5828 33333, 5826 33336, 5824 33339, 5821 33342, 5817 33342, 5813 33341, 5808 33340, 5803 33339, 5800 33338)) |

I would like to convert it into the following format: if POINT then (4495, 33442) if POLYGON then [(5810, 33296), (5813, 33297), (5816, 33299), (5819, 33301), (5822, 33303), (5826, 33306), (5829, 33307), (5833, 33307), (5836, 33308), (5837, 33312), (5837, 33316), (5836, 33319), (5834, 33323), (5832, 33327), (5830, 33330), (5828, 33333), (5826, 33336), (5824, 33339), (5821, 33342), (5817, 33342), (5813, 33341), (5808, 33340), (5803, 33339), (5800, 33338)]. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
op2=[]
for st, shape in zip(df['data'],df['shape']):
    if 'POINT' in shape:
        val=re.findall('\([0-9., ]+\)', st)[-1]
        op2.append("({})".format(", ".join(re.findall(r"\d+", val))))
        #op2_list = [ast.literal_eval(l) for l in op2]
        #poi = [Point(i).wkt for i in op2_list]
    else:  # Polygon
        val=re.findall('\([0-9., ]+\)', st)[-1]
        paran=val.replace(', ', '),(')
        fin=paran.replace(' ', ',')
        op2.append(fin)
        
data['converted']=pd.DataFrame(op2)
```

Desired output:

| shape | data | converted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POINT | POINT (4495 33442) | (4495, 33442) |
| POLYGON | POLYGON ((6324 32691, 6326 32691, 6330 32691, 6333 32693, 6332 32696, 6329 32700, 6328 32704, 6327 32707, 6325 32710, 6322 32713, 6319 32716, 6316 32719, 6313 32722, 6310 32725, 6307 32728, 6303 32728, 6299 32727, 6295 32727, 6291 32730, 6288 32733, 6285 32735, 6281 32735, 6277 32735, 6275 32732, 6274 32729, 6274 32725, 6272 32722, 6269 32720, 6265 32719, 6261 32719, 6258 32716, 6257 32712, 6259 32708, 6262 32705, 6265 32702, 6268 32701, 6272 32701, 6276 32701, 6279 32702, 6283 32702, 6287 32702, 6291 32699, 6294 32696, 6297 32693, 6300 32692, 6304 32692, 6308 32692, 6312 32692, 6316 32692, 6320 32693, 6324 32691)) | [(6324, 32691), (6326, 32691), (6330, 32691), (6333, 32693), (6332, 32696), (6329, 32700), (6328, 32704), (6327, 32707), (6325, 32710), (6322, 32713), (6319, 32716), (6316, 32719), (6313, 32722), (6310, 32725), (6307, 32728), (6303, 32728), (6299, 32727), (6295, 32727), (6291, 32730), (6288 ,32733), (6285, 32735), (6281, 32735), (6277, 32735), (6275, 32732), (6274, 32729), (6274, 32725), (6272, 32722), (6269, 32720), (6265, 32719), (6261, 32719), (6258, 32716), (6257, 32712), (6259, 32708), (6262, 32705), (6265, 32702), (6268, 32701), (6272, 32701), (6276, 32701), (6279, 32702), (6283, 32702), (6287, 32702), (6291, 32699), (6294, 32696), (6297, 32693), (6300, 32692), (6304, 32692), (6308, 32692), (6312, 32692), (6316, 32692), (6320, 32693), (6324, 32691)] |
| POINT | POINT (4673 33465) | (4673, 33465) |
| POLYGON | POLYGON ((5810 33296, 5813 33297, 5816 33299, 5819 33301, 5822 33303, 5826 33306, 5829 33307, 5833 33307, 5836 33308, 5837 33312, 5837 33316, 5836 33319, 5834 33323, 5832 33327, 5830 33330, 5828 33333, 5826 33336, 5824 33339, 5821 33342, 5817 33342, 5813 33341, 5808 33340, 5803 33339, 5800 33338)) | [(5810, 33296), (5813, 33297), (5816, 33299), (5819, 33301), (5822, 33303), (5826, 33306), (5829, 33307), (5833, 33307), (5836, 33308), (5837, 33312), (5837, 33316), (5836, 33319), (5834, 33323), (5832, 33327), (5830, 33330), (5828, 33333), (5826, 33336), (5824, 33339), (5821, 33342), (5817, 33342), (5813, 33341), (5808, 33340), (5803, 33339), (5800, 33338)] |

This does not convert the polygons. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This function will format the polygon strings correctly:

```
def format_polygon(s):
    return [tuple([float(i) for i in x.split(" ")]) for x in s[10:-2].split(", ")]
```

and this code will format the point strings correctly:

```
def format_point(s):
    return tuple([float(i) for i in s[7:-1].split(" ")])
```

they can then be applied to your dataframe like so:

```
df[df["shape"]=="POINT"]["data"] = df[df["shape"]=="POINT"]["data"].apply(lambda x: format_point(x))
df[df["shape"]=="POLYGON"]["data"] = df[df["shape"]=="POLYGON"]["data"].apply(lambda x: format_polygon(x))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I get the following error ```ValueError: could not convert string to float: ```

Comment: @disukumo Sorry, error in my code, I've edited it so it should work now